# Disable Logger for websockets Package in Python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, websocket

I am using the `websockets` package to create a websocket server in python; at the same time I am heavily using the `logging` in different log-levels.

The `websockets` [documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api.html#module-websockets.protocol) mentions the logger configuration and that it could be changed to the log-level `ERROR` using

```
     logger = logging.getLogger('websockets.server')
     logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
     logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

This, however, does not have any effect in my code, wherever I place it (below the import, before the `websockets` import, within `__main__`). I'd like to have two configurations - one global logging configuration and the logger-configuration of the websockets server.

Another option would be to disable the logging completely for the websockets module but I can't figure out how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out it is not only the `websockets.server` that is emitting lots of debug messages, there's other ones too. I've ended up hunting down those packages by using the `%(name)s` field in the root logger configuration and could find `websockets.protocol` being responsible for the additional messages.

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s  %(message)s',
    datefmt='(%H:%M:%S)')

# disable all loggers from different files
logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('asyncio.coroutines').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('websockets.server').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('websockets.protocol').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you start a websocket, set:

```
websocket.enableTrace(False)
```

No DEBUG and hart beat messages will be logged or shown in the console.

My example code:

```
def start_websocket(url, listen_method):
"""
Start a websocket connection.

:param url: string
:param listen_method: method
"""
# Enable or Disable logging
websocket.enableTrace(False)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    url,
    on_message=listen_method,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_close=on_close
)

ws.on_open = on_open

ws.run_forever(ping_interval=3, ping_timeout=2)
```